# camera button on one page and image to be displayed on other

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a image editing application i have camera and gallery buttons on my home view controller lets say viewcontroller1.
Process is : Clicking on gallery the "photo gallery " should open up user should be able to choose 1 image and that image should be displayed on viewcontroller2.Similarly with camera.
I am not able to figure out how to acieve this.

Comment: @matt my camera button is in the the viewcontroller that is ahead of where i want my image to be seen after being selected.

Comment: @matt thanks for understanding. The simple thing seems tricky to me. i am watching videos where the camera and the gallery button are on the same page with imageview but here the buttons are on differnt view controllers and image view on the other. Just help me out.

Comment: For navigating from one UIViewController to another on buttons click event you have to use UINavigationController.

Comment: @DhavalD. yeah and what about the image that i choose how will it go to next viewcontroller?

Comment: @matt you still do'nt understand.